# BeautifulSoup4 IndexError: list index out of range?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am learning about BS4 and I can't figure out what this code does and why does this code throw out an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/Untitled1.py", line 17, in <module>
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[3]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The python code using bs4 is:

```
for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2]:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    print("value:%s,value 2:%s,value3:%s" \
        (tds[0].text,tds[1].text,tds[2].text))
```

Thank you so much for reading this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically BeautifulSoup is a python library that helps you pulling the data out of the HTML and XML files, all you have to do is just apply some set of rules to pull the data out of Web page HTML files.

```
for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2]:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    print("value:%s,value 2:%s,value3:%s" \
        (tds[0].text,tds[1].text,tds[2].text))
```

This above piece of code just applying some set of rules like for every **'tr'** iteration variable inside of **soup** variable find all of the **'tr'** tag element having index of value **2**, and then inside of for loop you have created a **tds** variable storing the return value of every **'tr'** iterated variable by finding all **'td'** tag element inside of every **'tr'** iterated variable.
Then the code just tried to print **3 string values** as **value**, **value2**, **value3** where the code tried to display the **text** **value** of the **tds** variable of **index 0, 1, and 2**.

But unfortunately this code throws an **IndexError at line 17 : `for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2]`.** 
For your kind information the index value you are trying to fetch is not inside of soup variable where you are trying to fetch **'tr'** tag element.
So it is asking you to try some other index value that is present inside of the soup variable **'tr'** tag element.
That's why the error is saying list index is out of range.

Comment: Thank you so much for your nice explanation. By "soup variable" you mean some information inside <tr>~~~</tr> right? thank you!

Comment: The below code will help you to understand what I mean by soup variable:-

url = "https://www.example.com/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")

The soup varibale is the variable that has all of the content stored of an html file of a specific web page that you are trying to scrape.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with this kind of error you can first test existence of list element before you work with it, and than you have to test whether list has 3 elements at all:

```
if soup.find_all('tr'): # test if element exists
    if len(soup.find_all('tr')>2): # if list exists test whether it has more than 2 elements
        for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2]:
            tds = tr.find_all('td')
            print("value:%s,value 2:%s,value3:%s" \
            (tds[0].text,tds[1].text,tds[2].text))
    else: tds = "tr have less than 3 rows"
else: tds = "tr doesn't exists"
```